# How to repeat all column values for each row in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table that has two columns:

```
Height Width
400    200
500    300
600    400
700
800
...
```

And need to create a second table next to it to repeat entire column height for each value in the width column, whilst copying, to basically get every possible combination:

```
Height Width
400    200
500    200
600    200
700    200
800    200
400    300
500    300
600    300
700    300
800    300
```

Comment: follow posting rules; remove *please*, and be clear in your explanations

Comment: sorry did not realise and was edited by someone so reads good now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I could think of running nested loops. You might need to modify the code below depending on the structure of your sheets, but it should get you going.

```
Sub loops()

Dim n_height, n_width, c As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

n_height = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming height is in column A
n_width = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming width is in column B

c = 2

For i = 2 To n_height
    For j = 2 To n_width
        .Range("D" & c).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value 'Prints heights in column D
        .Range("E" & c).Value = .Range("B" & j).Value 'Prints widths in column E
        c = c + 1
    Next j
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, that has worked wonderfully. Will save me a couple of hours over three days work thank you so much

Comment: I've a similar question with bit more conditions in another thread if you can help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329209/excel-get-all-multiples-of-column-a-b-if-for-similar-value-of-column-c